# Setting up chatbot command in discord.js 12

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i wanted to make a chatbot command like a example of command
?bsetchatbot [channel name]
heres a syntax of the command and here what code i used
note - i already impoted required modules

```
const Chat = require("easy-discord-chatbot");
const chat = new Chat({ name: "Blabbermouth" });
if (message.content === "?bsetchatbot") {
  channelname = message.mentions.channels.first()
 if(!channelname) { 
 return message.channel.send("Pleease Mention A channel!")
 }

 if(message.channel.name === `${channelname}` && !message.author.bot) {    
    let reply = await chat.chat(message.content)
    message.channel.send(reply)
  }
  message.channel.send(`Chat Bot Channel is set as ${channelname}`) 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't save the channel where people can chat with the bot. I recommend to save the channel with the `ValueSaver` package as you can can save it and import it again when your server shut down. Here is an example

```js
const { ValueSaver } = require('valuesaver');
const channels = new ValueSaver();
channels.import(`channels`); // Import the ValueSaver named 'channels' if a save exists with this name

const { Client } = require('discord.js');

const Chat = require('easy-discord-chatbot');
const chat = new Chat({name: 'Blabbermouth'});

const client = new Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
   console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag} on ${new Date().toString()}`);
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === `DM`) return;

    let args = message.content.substring(1).split(" ");

    const _channelid = channels.get(message.guild.id); // Get the channel id
    if(_channelid){ // If there has been set a channel
         if(message.channel.id === _channelid){ // If the channel is the chat channel
              let reply = await chat.chat(encodeURI(message.content));
              message.channel.send(reply).catch(console.log)
         }
    }

    if(message.content.startsWith('?')){
        switch(args[0].toLowerCase()){
            case 'bsetchatbot':
                const channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
                if(!channel) return message.channel.send(`Please mention a channel to set the chat channel`).catch(console.log);
                channels.set(message.guild.id, channel.id); // Access the channel id by the guild id
                channels.save(`channels`); // Create a new save with the name 'channels'
                break;
        }
     }
});

client.login('Your Token');
```

ValueSaver: https://npmjs.com/package/valuesaver